# Eevee Render white blast problem

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I set up a short test sequence for an animation and I want to render it with Eevee to render it fast. But as you can see, white explosions occur at some points in the pallets of the tank. I tried many things but couldn't find a solution. Since I don't use Eevee much, I don't know what to do to prevent this from happening? Anyone have any suggestions for a solution?

[image]
First Frame

[image]
Second Frame

Comment: Hello, it's really hard to see what is the problem. Could you post a higher resolution image ?

Comment: The images are quite small, it is hard to see what your problem is. Also, it may be helpful to upload your blendfile to https://blend-exchange.com/